# Change the name of an installed plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have installed a third-party plugin for my wordpress site. What I want is to rename that plugin so that it matches my purpose for installing it. Is it possible?

The plugin I'm trying to modify is CubePoints.. It's a pointing system for the users. But for the sake of better understanding, I'll be calling it MyPoints or something like that.a

When I rename it in the plugin `PHP` file, it affects only the plugin listing.

But it has a separate menu in the left panel. What I need is it to take effect there, so that the user can see the modified name in their user panel.

Comment: How will changing the name match the purpose of installing it? You risk breaking the update engine or if you manage to update the plugin, your changes will be overwritten.

Comment: It's a pointing system for users. The plugin is called CubePoint.. so I'm going to name it MyPoints or something so as to not to confuse the users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the plugin directory structure

> yoursite\wp-content\plugins\ [editing-plugin-folder]

open the folder you will find a .php file in there, edit the file using any editor. you can change the name of the plugin in commented area

```
/*
Plugin Name: Name according to you
Plugin URI:

*/
```

save the file **refresh** your **wp-admin**  **dashboard** and there you go .

Comment: I did so.. but it changes the plugin name in the plugin listing, but not in the wordpress admin left panel. What should I do?

Comment: What you exactly want to do ? Please tell me the exact location of the plugin in side dashboard, Is it in settings sub menu or it has a separate menu ?

Comment: check my main post edit..

Comment: edit the file cp_admin.php
in initial 8th line you will get this code `add_menu_page('CubePoints', 'CubePoints', 'manage_options', 'cp_admin_manage', 'cp_admin_manage');` replace this code with this code `add_menu_page('CubePoints', 'Name of Menu You want', 'manage_options', 'cp_admin_manage', 'cp_admin_manage');` anything else you need feel free to ask.

Comment: brilliant.. it worked.. but when a user clicks `My Points` in the user panel menu.. it shows `CubePoints - My Points` there.. could anything be done about it?

Comment: I think you're talking about the the pages that are displaying in the admin panel names right ? or something else ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11457/discussion-between-kaushik-and-sam-dg)

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a while.. The issue is that when a user click on the `modified menu name` in his user panel.. the page that is displayed has the text `CubePoints - My Points` on the top.. ping me if you're available on chat

Answer (score 3):

Your changes will be overridden in a future plugin update.
As a more long term solution I'd recommend using a translation plugin to modify the name OR hook into WP menu generation process and modify the plugin(s) you need.